# the HORZSIZE of the GetDeviceCaps

Tags: winapi, gdi

I am reading the Programming Windows 5th edition.This book told me that the HORZSIZE=25.4*HORZRES/LOGPIXELSX. And the following picture is my result:

[image]

If caculating the HORZSIZE by using the formula,It should be 25.4*1280/96=338.6666....

How could this happen?

I'm looking forward to your answer!

BTW:I'm using the laptop,Geforce 8400M GS,15.4inches.resolution 1280*800,Windows 7.

Comment: I'm getting the same result on my laptop: 1600 pixels, 96 dpi, 564 mm.  The calculation is based on 72 dpi.  No idea why, nobody ever uses that.

Comment: @HansPassant,that's OS's problem,when this problem came out,I didn't read the following part after this.The book told us that the formula is only significant for the Windows 98,as for win NT,It depends on the resolution ,you can try it ,after changing the resolution,the HORZSIZE will change.However,if you change the DPI,the HORZSIZE won't change.

Comment: Maybe changing DPI do not affect HORSIZE. AFAIK LOGPIXELSX is constant. See wingdi.h.

Comment: @Xearinox,It depends on the OS,I tried it in the Win98, changing DPI can affect the final result.

Comment: I never tested in Win 98. :-) But is interesting problem.

Comment: From Petzold book: The difference in Windows NT is that the HORZSIZE and VERTSIZE values are fixed to indicate a standard monitor size. For common adapters, the values of HORZSIZE
and VERTSIZE you'll obtain are 320 and 240 millimeters, respectively. These values are the same regardless of what pixel dimension you choose. Therefore, these
values are inconsistent with the values you obtain from GetDeviceCaps with the HORZRES, VERTRES, LOGPIXELSX, and LOGPIXELSY indices.

Comment: Maybe this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/4bdacf58-ead6-418f-843a-8bfcc6be29d9/  ????

Answer (score 0):

Very often HORZSIZE and LOGPIXELSX metrics are not valid for computer displays.
This is be because of monitor driver which provides wrong information about monitor's width.
At the same time these settings works quite good for printers.

BTW, in your formula
HORZRES/LOGPIXELSX gives you width of monitor in inches and multiplication by 25.4 converts inches to mm.

You may fix that problem by measuring monitor width (with help of ruler ) and calculating correct DPI.